# How do I convert videos to H.265/HEVC format in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, codecs, video-conversion, hevc

I see that H.265/HEVC encoding is gathering momentum but under some versions of Ubuntu it is not all that easy to produce H.265 video streams.

How should I go about using x265, in a manner that *integrates* with Ubuntu (*especially* the LTS releases Trusty and Xenial), to produce HEVC video files under Ubuntu?

**References:**

1. [x265 HEVC Encoder](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/wiki/Home): The commandline encoder
2. [x265](http://www.videolan.org/developers/x265.html): Videolan site

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution so far on my system has been:

1. For Trusty Tahr 14.04 LTS: use an [up to date FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and the most recent x265, which necessitates some compiling and subsequent packaging
2. For Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS: simply run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ffmpeg  libavcodec-extra
   ```

With *either* of the previous methods then use the following:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
   -c:v libx265 -preset slow -x265-params crf=22 \
   -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k \
   output.mp4
```

Note that this creates an mp3 audio stream as well as an h.265 video stream. To create an aac stream the line `-c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k` could be replaced with the following:

```
-c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 128k
```

The `-strict experimental` option will *not* be required if your copy of FFmpeg was released after December 2015 when development of the native aac encoder [matured](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=d9791a8656b5580756d5b7ecc315057e8cd4255e). Bear in mind that this option *will still be required* for the repository FFmpeg for Xenial Xerus 16.04 LTS.

**References:**

- [FFmpeg trac: FFmpeg and H.265 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265)
- [FFmpeg git: aacenc: remove the experimental flag](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=d9791a8656b5580756d5b7ecc315057e8cd4255e)

Comment: That's pretty much what I did, except I used the experimental AAC encoder built-in to FFMpeg.

Comment: Interestingly enough the experimental aac encoder is no longer 'experimental' in git FFmpeg from December 2015.

Comment: Added in the option of using the FFmpeg native aac encoder...

Answer (score 4):

## Method 01

You can install Internet friendly media encoder:

[image]

Run these commands in your Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:upubuntu-com/multimedia  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install ifme
```

Now you can open the program **ifme** from Dash.

[source](http://www.upubuntu.com/2015/01/how-to-convert-videos-from-and-to-h265.html)

## Method 02

Once you compiled the program following the instructions in [here](https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265/wiki/Home) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCDEVJI0efk),  first you have to encode the video into YUV format:

```
avconv -i MyVideo.mp4 MyVideo.yuv
```

Then you can convert YUV video into x265 format:

```
./x265 --input-res 640x360 --fps 24000/100 MyVideo.yuv -o MyVideo.h265
```

Comment: Or if you don't like big uncompressed files pipe the output of avconv against x265. (it looks like this for ffmpeg+x264: `ffmpeg -i "INPUT" -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - | x264 --demuxer y4m - --profile High10 --preset slower --crf 20 --video-filter -o "OUTPUT" -`)

Comment: @LiveWireBT: That's cleaver!

Answer (score 3):

This script worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mpg -pix_fmt yuv420p -f yuv4mpegpipe - |\
     x265-10bit --profile main10 --preset slower --crf 20 --input - --y4m -o output_file.mpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Start VLC with the file you wish to convert, stop the video from playing, reset to start of file, then open the media menu, select the convert/save option, select H265 and MP3, then give the file a new name using the output file selection, and wait for the process to finish.  There is no easier way.